# How to show iTerm2 badge in VS Code integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, badge, iterm2

I configured iTerm2 to show badge on the right-top corner to see the development context. It's working well in iTerm2 but not working in VS Code.

Of course, I changed terminal app in VS Code user settings but seems it's not applied on integrated terminal.

Any solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

> Of course, I changed terminal app in VSCode user settings

VS Code's integrated terminal uses [xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js). As far as I am aware, there is no such thing as "changing terminal app in VS Code user settings". You can change [terminal *profile*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles), but that mostly has to do with what [*shell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) is used, and a shell is not a terminal. As far as I am aware, neither VS Code's integrated terminal, nor xterm.js which it is built on support iTerm2's badge feature. If you want such a feature, you'd need to [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).